# jquery noConflict not working in php include()

Tags: jquery, php-include

jquery.noConflict doesnt work for some reason when loading from an exernal file using php includes? aslo noticed that maybe some scripts arent fully loading as well?

---

mainfile.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.jquery/jquery.1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<?
include 'extrn_file.php';
?>
```

// end

//extrn_file.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.jquery/jquery.1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script> $jq132 = jQuery.noConflict(true); </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/animate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
execute_skills_doc();

function execute_skills_doc(){
$jq132(document).ready(function() {
alert("yes");//nothing happens
});

}
```

//end

Comment: Including two different versions of jQuery will cause all sorts of havoc!

Comment: Why would you want to load 2 jQuery in the first place?

Comment: trying to fork some code, which only works in an older version of jQuery :(

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. noConflict is battle proven and is working fine, PHP include or not is irrelevant. Something in your code is incorrect. The problem is not in the pasted code. Try to put an online version of it. (btw - my guess - once you put that online version on, you'll find the typo).

Comment: this comment needs a lot more research: `"aslo noticed that maybe some scripts arent fully loading as well"`. Could be some failing php not outputing the whole page??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use multiple version of `jQuery` on the same page you have to `noConflict()` the first before you load the second. Since your PHP include just pulls the contents of the two files together, you are ending up with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.jquery/jquery.1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.jquery/jquery.1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script> $jq132 = jQuery.noConflict(true); </script>
```

What you really want would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.jquery/jquery.1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // set version 1.8.2 to variable and remove globals
    $jq182 = jQuery.noConflict(true); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.jquery/jquery.1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // return jQuery version
    function getVersion(jq){
        return jq().jquery;
    }

    // set version 1.3.2 to variable and remove globals
    $jq132 = jQuery.noConflict(true); 
    // reset jQuery variable to 1.8.2
    jQuery = $jq182.noConflict();

    // your code that uses $ variable and jQuery 1.3.2
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){ alert('Using $ v'+getVersion($)+'!'); });
    })($jq132);

    // your code that uses $ variable and jQuery 1.8.2
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){ alert('Using $ v'+getVersion($)+'!'); });
    })($jq182);

    // your code that uses jQuery variable and jQuery 1.8.2
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ alert('Using jQuery v'+getVersion(jQuery)+'!'); });

</script>​
```

At this point you will have version `1.8.2` loaded into the `$jq182` and `jQuery` variables and `1.3.2` loaded into the `$jq132` variable. The code above will alert the variable used and version of each. You can see an example using the Google API hosted libraries here: http://jsfiddle.net/2kX3E/